# Font doing FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text) on every refresh on every page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am wondering why I am having this issue... First time I load everything

[image]

After first time, I get (ServiceWorker) as Size but I still see the FOUT happening, not sure why

[image]

Maybe I am not loading the cached fonts correctly?
I tried importing used fonts in css @font-face via preload link but still flashing every time

This is my `_app.jsx`

```
import ThemeProvider from '@material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider'
import theme from 'theme'
import { wrapper } from 'store'
import '../styles/slick.css'

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      {globalStyle}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(App)

const globalStyle = (
  <style jsx global>{`
    html,
    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans',
        'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    code {
      font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;
    }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          src: local('Poppins-Regular'), url('/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf');
          font-display: swap;
}
  `}</style>
)
```

And this is my `_document.jsx` render

```
render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="es">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />

          {!ENV.INDEX_SITE && <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />}

          <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous" />

          {/* PWA Icons */}
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/icons/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/icons/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/icons/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/icons/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/icons/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/icons/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
```

I am trying to use it on the material ui theme along with clsx by adding the `poppins` class

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      color: COLORS.black,
      '&.poppins': { fontFamily: 'Poppins' },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: where are you using Poppins? I'm not seeing any of your sample code using it, only the `@font-face` declaration. Also, any `@font-face` declarations should be at the very top and loaded before any of your other css (or JS for that matter). For instance, Google Fonts suggest you put their `<link/>` tag as far up / at the top of your `<head>` as possible to make sure it loads as quickly as possible / before it needs to be used.

Comment: @andersryanc I edited the question and added where I am using Poppins (with material ui theme). I also tried moving both @font-face in `<style jsx global>` and the `<link/>` tag to the very top but FOUT keeps happening

Comment: @Gonzalo Did you manage to solve this? I am experiencing the same issue. I'm not using google fonts though, I have a web font in my public folder. Every time a rerender happens I get a FOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still experiencing this, you should try [upgrading to mui v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/)

Make sure to completely [remove any usage and also the library itself](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#remove-old-packages) from `package.json`  and completely finish the migration before checking it out. Once I fully upgraded all the project to v5 (in my case with emotion) all the FOUC issues I was having were fixed.

**EDIT:**

NextJS introduced `@next/font` in their [version 13](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#nextfont) which may help solve this in a more native way.

`Custom fonts are also supported, including support for automatic self-hosting, caching, and preloading of font files.`

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local';

const myFont = localFont({ src: './my-font.woff2' });

<html className={myFont.className}>
```